# Realtime updates for subscribers

Tags: .net, winforms, message-queue

*In short*: I have 2 windows applications(written using .NET) and need to pass updates from one to another.
**Example:** operator has his program that receives a call. He needs to fill details about caller in his program. Dispatcher has another program(that uses same database) and after operator started to fill information about caller-he must see that typed sentences in "realtime". The idea is that he must have some sort of card about caller and see its updates. The problem here is: i want to do as less calls to the database as possible, because there can be many dispatchers and operators at the same time.
Ive heard about MQ message brokers(like rabbitMQ, activeMQ), but havent used them yet(just "heard"), and dont really now if they are applicable in such situation.

P.S. hope ive described the question normally. Please tell me if i wrote something wrongly or not clearly. Thank you.

Comment: Personally, I would "communicate" via the database only. I.e. there is kind of notification table where clients write into and others poll in regular intervals for new information.

Comment: @Uwe Keim, thought about that, but in the project i must use services to communicate with database..That adds some latency, tho sure i can use async check/sends. Thank you for the answer. Tho i still hope to see some "out of the box" solution for such situations if it exists, because with raw service calls there may be some problems with receivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer i wanted: [Publish/Subscribe samples with RabbitMQ in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951477/publish-subscribe-samples-with-rabbitmq-in-net/5951709#5951709)