# Publish/Subscribe samples with RabbitMQ in .NET

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, messagebroker

I've built this sample: [Getting Started With RabbitMQ in .net](http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-in-dotnet/), but made 2 programs:

- one-publisher
- one-subscriber

I'm using `BasicPublish` to publish and `BasicAck` to listen as in example. If I run one publisher and several subscribers-on every "send message" from publisher- only one subscriber gets it. So that there is some order (as subscribers were started) in which publisher sends message to subscribers, and I want to send one message to all subscribers. What is wrong with that sample? May be you can provide working sample of publisher/subscribers message exchange via RabbitMq?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The example you link to uses simple queueing without an exchange, which ensures that only a single consumer will handle the message. To support pub/sub in RabbitMQ, you need to first create an Exchange, and then have each subscriber bind a Queue on that Exchange. The producer then sends messages to the Exchange, which will publish the message to each Queue that has been bound to it (at least with the simple Fanout exchange type. Routing can be achieved with Direct and Topic exchanges.)

For a Java sample (which could be converted to C# pretty easily) please see [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html).

**Edit:**
Updated .Net version can be found [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html)

Comment: Just changed that java code to c# and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I've added a new tutorial about this [Getting Started With RabbitMQ in .net](http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-in-net-%E2%80%93-part-3/)

Comment: Thank you - so far your example is the only one I've seen that does asynchronous subscriptions in .NET. Calling Invoke on a delegate seems "retro" - is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There are also some [official sources](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/tree/master/dotnet) now.